# align images with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

Hi i need to align the images with css
I use a content called "boton" the link of the site is www.newprincess.cl
and I need to align like this  http://imageshack.us/f/69/btnr.jpg/
How can do that?? 
help me please
very thanks

Comment: I try coded separated image in different div content but doesn't work ,

Answer (score 1):

change your CSS as follow

```
#boton {
    height: 120px;
    width: 157px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#boton #oneimg {
    top:9px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
}

#boton #twoimg {
    top:38px;
    position:absolute;  
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: auto;      
    margin-left: 25px;

}

#boton #threeimg {
    top:58px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: 28px;      
}
```

And change your HTML code as follow

```
<div id="boton">
    <div id="threeimg"><img src="salir.png" border="0"></div>
    <div id="twoimg"><img src="entrar.png" border="0"></div>
    <div id="oneimg"><img src="18.png" border="0"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your images each an `id=` property (I'm sure you'll be able to figure out the names I use):

```
#salir {
  position: relative;
  top: -16px;
}

#entrar-link {
  display: block;
}

#entrar {
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
}

#boton {
  text-align: center;
}
```